# Подсветка выпадающего меню.без JS

Tags: html, css, menu, dropdown

Нужно добавить подсветку над пунктом меню который в фокусе. Как это лучше реализовать?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.menu {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 65px;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

.menu #backlightZone {
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: white;
  display: block;
  border: 1px #E2DDD8 solid;
}

.menu #menu {
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
}

.menu #menu li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.menu #menu a {
  display: block;
  padding: 0px 15px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #7B7B7B;
  font-family: "FuturaBTLight";
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 60px;
}

.menu #menu li:hover>a {
  color: #1C285B;
}

.menu #menu li:hover>ul {
  display: block;
}

.menu #menu li ul {
  display: none;
  background-color: #1D275A;
  width: 200px;
  height: 140px;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: left;
  ;
}

.menu #menu li ul li a {
  line-height: 20px;
  text-transform: none;
  color: white;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 11px;
}

.menu #menu li ul li a:hover {
  color: #C4AB2E;
}
```

```html
<section class="menu">
  <div id="backlightZone">
    <div class="backlight" id="weddingBL"></div>
  </div>
  <ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="">home</a></li>
    <li><a href="">wedding</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">Simple and Elegant</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Pebble paper</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Pocket invitations</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Elegant</a></li>

      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">baby</a></li>
    <li><a href="">quinces/mitzvah</a></li>
    <li><a href="">social</a></li>
    <li><a href="">other products/services</a></li>
    <li><a href="">online consultation</a></li>
    <li><a href="">blog</a></li>
    <li><a href="">white papers</a></li>
    <li><a href="">contact us</a></li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

Comment: Поясните, что означает "пункт меню в фокусе". Пункт, соответствующий активной странице?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать вот так :

```css
.menu {
  width: 100%
  height: 65px;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box
}
.menu #menu {
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
}
.menu #menu:before{
  content:'';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #ccc;
  z-index: 3
}

.menu #menu li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.menu #menu a {
  display: block;
  padding: 0px 15px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #7B7B7B;
  font-family: "FuturaBTLight";
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 60px;
}
.menu #menu > li:hover:before,
.menu #menu > li:focus:before{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: #1D275A;
  
}
.menu #menu li:hover > a {
  color: #1C285B;
}

.menu #menu li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}

.menu #menu li ul {
  display: none;
  background-color: #1D275A;
  width: 200px;
  height: 140px;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: left;
  ;
}

.menu #menu li ul li a {
  line-height: 20px;
  text-transform: none;
  color: white;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 11px;
}

.menu #menu li ul li a:hover {
  color: #C4AB2E;
}
```

```html
<section class="menu">
  <ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="">home</a></li>
    <li><a href="">wedding</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">Simple and Elegant</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Pebble paper</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Pocket invitations</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Elegant</a></li>

      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">baby</a></li>
    <li><a href="">quinces/mitzvah</a></li>
    <li><a href="">social</a></li>
    <li><a href="">other products/services</a></li>
    <li><a href="">online consultation</a></li>
    <li><a href="">blog</a></li>
    <li><a href="">white papers</a></li>
    <li><a href="">contact us</a></li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

Comment: Красота, то что надо. Я был бы признателен ещё за небольшое пояснения изминениям. К примеру не до конца понял почему он подсвечивал весь ':before' До того как задал '.menu #menu li' параметр 'position: relative;'

Comment: @adckiykpolb
Для :before задано значение position: absolute; которое уже работает от области объекта одного из родителей с значением position: relative;
А так то правила работали, просто уходили куда-то.

Answer (score 1):

Если я Вас правильно понял то можно так: `.menu #menu li:hover { border-top: 2px solid red; }`

```css
.menu {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 65px;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

.menu #backlightZone {
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: white;
  display: block;
  border: 1px #E2DDD8 solid;
}

.menu #menu {
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
}

.menu #menu li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.menu #menu li:hover {
  border-top: 2px solid red;
}

.menu #menu a {
  display: block;
  padding: 0px 15px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #7B7B7B;
  font-family: "FuturaBTLight";
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 60px;
}

.menu #menu li:hover>a {
  color: #1C285B;
}

.menu #menu li:hover>ul {
  display: block;
}

.menu #menu li ul {
  display: none;
  background-color: #1D275A;
  width: 200px;
  height: 140px;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: left;
  ;
}

.menu #menu li ul li a {
  line-height: 20px;
  text-transform: none;
  color: white;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 11px;
}

.menu #menu li ul li a:hover {
  color: #C4AB2E;
}
```

```html
<section class="menu">
  <div id="backlightZone">
    <div class="backlight" id="weddingBL"></div>
  </div>
  <ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="">home</a></li>
    <li><a href="">wedding</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">Simple and Elegant</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Pebble paper</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Pocket invitations</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Elegant</a></li>

      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">baby</a></li>
    <li><a href="">quinces/mitzvah</a></li>
    <li><a href="">social</a></li>
    <li><a href="">other products/services</a></li>
    <li><a href="">online consultation</a></li>
    <li><a href="">blog</a></li>
    <li><a href="">white papers</a></li>
    <li><a href="">contact us</a></li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

Comment: Дмитрий, почти правильно, только так должно быть выше, в сером прямоугольнике над меню.